# Why the type parameter in Enum declaration contains recursive type bounds?

Tags: java, generics, enums

```
  public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
            implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {
     // All code goes here

    }
```

In the code above why there is recursive type bound for the type parameter of the `Enum` and why is missing for the portion that contains `Comparable<E>` . In other words why it is `Comparable<E>` and not `Comparable<E extends Comparable<E>>`

Comment: "In other words why ... not Comparable<<E> extends Comparable<E>>" because that is not valid Java syntax

Comment: @newacct If `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is valid Java syntax why not `Comparable<E extends Comparable<E>>`?. I have edited the question btw ?Are you saying not valid because of the extra `<>` around `E` that I have removed ?

Comment: No. Bounds on type parameters can only be specified where the type parameter is declared. For generic classes, the type parameters are declared right after the name of the class in the class declaration, so e.g. in the `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`. For generic methods, the type parameters are declared before the return type. Anywhere else, including in specifying superclasses or interfaces in your example, you are just using the type parameter; you cannot specify bounds on it.

Comment: @newacct thanks for the clarification. It was useful information .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is defining `E` and limiting it's type.

By the time you get to `Comparable<E>` `E` is now defined so you don't need to further qualify it.

`Comparable<<E> extends Comparable<E>>` would just be silly. If you mean something like `Comparable<E extends Enum<E>>` then you wouldn't need it because `E` has been defined and filtered already. At this point you are now informing the user more about what objects of this class do, i.e. they implement the `Comparable<E>` interface.

`Enum` types have recursive type bounds because they are a recursive type, i.e. an `enum` **is** an `Enum` of itself (note the case difference).

Answer (score 0):

There may be no desire to bound the generic type parameter of the `Comparable` to a specific type, while the `Enum` must be bound to a type extending `Enum`.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Comparable<E extends Comparable<E>>` also. `Comparable<E>` is identical to `Comparable<E extends Enum<E>>` cause `E extends Enum<E>`, `Enum<E>` is identical to `Comparable<E>` due to inheritance. Therefore `Comparable<E>` identical to `Comparable<E extends Comparable<E>>`